# How to videoview.start()?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm not familiar to java or android development (just start reading about it yesterday). I want to call videoview with a certain url and pass some headers to it. I searched the web and found this method:

```
 package com.example.teste;

 import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.MediaController;
 import android.widget.VideoView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://s2.ratotv.com/magic/4866/1.mp4");
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Host", "ratotv.com");
        headers.put("Referer", "http://www.ratotv.net/movies/1038-kick-ass-2-agora-a-doer.html");

        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        // Use java reflection call the hide API:
        Method method;
     try {
         method = myVideoView.getClass().getMethod("setDataSource", new Class[] { Context.class, Uri.class, Map.class });
         method.invoke(myVideoView, new Object[] {this, uri, headers});
         myVideoView.start();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
}
```

However, videoplayback doesn't start.

Any help would be very much aprecciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: Yes...been reading about it for hours but with no luck. I attach the complete code

Comment: Can I ask why it's necessary to send the headers? If those aren't necessary, this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: The server requires those headers for the video to be played...
If you click the video file you'll get a 403 error. This won't happen if you pass the headers

Comment: Ok, understood. Are you catching any of the errors? Also, a potential problem is that `VideoView` doesn't have a method called `setDataSource()`, that method belongs to `MediaPlayer`.